# Visual Studio Code is auto formatting my js file that has markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I upgraded my visual studio code version 1.33.0 recently and am having issues with saving my files because they keep formatting when I save the document.

I have looked through the update - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_33 and opened up the javascript and javascriptreact languages in the settings.json file.

settings.json file

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "files.associations": {
    "*.scss": "scss"
  },
  "mssql.connections": [
    {
      "server": "localhost",
      "database": "",
      "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
      "user": "SA",
      "password": "",
      "emptyPasswordInput": false,
      "savePassword": true,
      "profileName": "localhost profile"
    }
  ],
  "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "php.validate.enable": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "[javascript]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": false,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

This does not matter, it ignores these preferences and auto formats it to VSCs auto default format. I am using .js files with react and switching the rsx is not an option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 levels of settings(User level, Workspace Level, Global) in VSC. Check if formatOnSave is false for all of them. 
If it still indents your code, then create a .editorconfig file in your project and mention your settings there. It gets the highest preference in VSC settings and will override all the others.

Comment: I just checked and it is false on all 3. what should the property be called in the editorconfig file?